# Save modificated WaveChannel32 from NAudio in .net

Tags: c#, .net, wav, naudio

I have a problem with saving my audio file on hard drive.
I'm using a WaveChannel32 class fron Naudio to make a Pan Effect on my played sound.
I want to save an audio on disk with changed Pan Values.
But when i want save, it a stream is endless and file grows up to big data Wav file.
Here is my code where i used it:

Making a stream:

```
        if (dialog.FileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
            pcm = NAudio.Wave.WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(new NAudio.Wave.Mp3FileReader(dialog.FileName));

        } else if (dialog.FileName.EndsWith(".wav")) {
            pcm = new NAudio.Wave.WaveChannel32(new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(dialog.FileName));               
        }

        stream = new NAudio.Wave.BlockAlignReductionStream(pcm); 

        if (stream == null) return;

        /* Wave Channel new instance (Pan) */
        wave_channel = new WaveChannel32(stream);
        wave_channel.Pan = panSlider1.Pan;

        /* Volume Meter */
        sample_channel = new SampleChannel(wave_channel, true);
        sample_channel.PreVolumeMeter += OnPostVolumeMeter;

        realtime_stream = new MeteringSampleProvider(sample_channel);
        realtime_stream.StreamVolume += OnPostVolumeMeter;

        /* Wave out initialize */
        wavo = new WaveOut();
        wavo.Init(realtime_stream);
        wavo.Stop();

        /* Volume Slider */
        sample_channel.Volume = volumeSlider1.Volume;
```

Saving a wav file code, I've try to cast WaveChannel32 to WaveStream

```
            WaveStream ch = wave_channel; 
            long outputLenght = 0; 

            using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(save_file_dialog.FileName + ".wav", ch.WaveFormat)) { 
                byte[] buffer = new byte[ch.WaveFormat.AverageBytesPerSecond * 4]; 
                while (true) { 
                    int bytesread = ch.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length); 
                    if (bytesread == 0) { 
                        break; 
                    } 
                    outputLenght += bytesread; 
                    if (outputLenght > Int32.MaxValue) { 
                        throw new InvalidOperationException("Plik nie może być większy niż 2GB"); 
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(buffer.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine(bytesread);
                    writer.Write(buffer, 0, bytesread); 
                } 
            }
```

How can i save it on hard drive with the same time as original?